# Project didn't compile - run anyway?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, if you hit f5 and get a compile error, a dialog pops up asking if you want to run with the last successful compiled version.  I never want to do this. Is there a way I can make it not show this dialog, and instead take me to the first compile error?  (Like Delphi used to do.)

Comment: Doesn't that dialog have a checkbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Tools, Options, Build and Run, and change `On run, when build or deployment errors occur`.